# MVC Html.TextBox (not For) client side validation styling

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validation-engine, html.textbox

I'm having aesthetic and consistency problems when it comes to client side validation errors in a certain View. The view consists of several (child) partial views and is basically a form using both MVC/Razor's `Html.Textbox()` and `Html.TextBoxFor()` in many places. In some of the partial views, I need the inputs not to be strongly typed, hence only `TextBox()`, and in these instances the validation won't trigger the client side styling of the input-boxes.

I know that the ModelState is not valid and the `Html.ValidationSummary()` shows the correct error messages from validation-errors triggered by both `TextBox()`'s and `TextBoxFor()`'s. However only the `TextBoxFor()`'s gets the class: "input-validation-error"

Question: How do I turn my `TextBox()`'s red when an error has fired? (simply put). I figure there's a value or attribute missing that JQuery validation triggers on.

**Code:**

Works: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Owner, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Doesn't: `@Html.TextBox(name, Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })`

**HTML output**

Works: `<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Input is required." id="Owner" name="Owner" type="text" value="">`

Doesn't: `<input class="form-control" id="Applicants_1__Name" name="Applicants[1].Name" type="text" value="">`

Comment: have you tried adding the data-val properties to the TextBox code e.g.
 @Html.TextBox(name, Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", data-val="true", data-val-required="Input is required" })

Comment: Yes, except that "data-val="true"", with hyphen, results in Cannot resolve symbol, but "data_val="true", data_val_required="Input is required" won't work either.

Comment: The `data-val-*` attributes are add by the html helpers by reading the `ModelMetadata` of the property. Since the value of `name` is not a property in your model there is nothing to read, so they wont be added! Use the strongly types helpers  (and if you think you can't, then you doing it wrong)

Comment: Sigh, then I wouldn't be asking this question would I? I've weighed in the time it would take to change them all, cause there are quite many of them. So there's no way to add the attributes "manually" to a `TextBox()`? Out of curiosity how would the equivalent `TextBoxFor()` look in my (see above) case?

Comment: Its just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` but I suspect that not the real problem since it looks like you have a collection, it which case its `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Applicants.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Applicants[i].Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>  m.Applicants[i].Name) }`. And you **cannot** use a partial to render a collection (at least not without some extra addons) - use a custom `EditorTemplate` for `Applicants` if you don't want to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just do the validation in jquery and then you can customise whatever you need.

you can then set the css of the input text box to be red easily;

```
$("#myInput").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

and reset it using

```
$("#myInput").css("border", "none")
```

Comment: I already have a form with 20+ inputs that validate perfectly server side and all errormessages comes through. The TextBoxFor()'s gets the styling and the others doesn't. Just need to know the essential difference when declaring the two that disables triggering of styles in client side somehow.

Comment: Ok. Just out of interest what's the reason you have to use TextBox instead of TextBoxFor..?

Comment: Can't have it strongly typed cause it has an unique identifier tied to it. I need to seperate between several child elements/objects with same type of inputs, hence var "name" in the code above that renders: id="Applicants_1__Name" name="Applicants[1].Name